# How can I remove the thick line from the table header row bottom

Tags: reactjs, html-table, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I just follow [the example](https://react-bootstrap.netlify.app/components/table/#small-table) for creating a table with the bootstrap `Table` element.

Here is [my StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-obbahp?file=src%2FApp.js,src%2Findex.js), I wonder why a thick black line exists at the bottom of the table header.

However, the example site does not have a thick black line exists at the bottom of the table header.

Is there something wrong? is it possible to remove the thick black line from the bottom of the table header?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is border assigned by bootstrap when you use Table group dividers. See [Bootstrap docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/content/tables/#table-group-dividers) for more details.

To get remove it add `borderTop: 'none'` to **tbody**. So updated component looks like below

```
import React from 'react';
import Table from 'react-bootstrap/Table';
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="m-4">
      <Table striped bordered hover>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Username</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody style={{ borderTop: 'none' }}>
          <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Mark</td>
            <td>Otto</td>
            <td>@mdo</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Jacob</td>
            <td>Thornton</td>
            <td>@fat</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td colSpan={2}>Larry the Bird</td>
            <td>@twitter</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Stackblitz Reproduction: https://react-ue5ckm.stackblitz.io

Comment: Alternatively, use CSS and a class to apply the style.

Answer (score 0):

You have to need override the following style

```css
.table>:not(:first-child) {
    border-top: 2px solid currentColor;
}
```

to remove border

```css
.table>:not(:first-child) {
    border-top: none;
}
```